# What data structure for tabs layout like IDEs?

Tags: data-structures, layout, tabs

What data structure should I use to mirror the behaviour of tabs like vscode or other IDEs?

I want a split horizontal and vertical.

Here an example in ASCII :

```
|------------|----------|-------|-----------|---------------------------------
|    file1   |  file2   |       |   file3   |
|------------|----------|-------|-----------|---------------------------------
|                               |
|                               |
|                               |
|                               |
|            file1              |                     file3
|                               |
|                               |
|                               |
|                               |
|                               |
|                               |
|---------|---------------------------------------------------------------------
|  file4  |
|---------|---------------------------------------------------------------------
|
|
|
|                                         file4
|
|
|
|
|
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I need this to be simple to layout in a tree of widgets.

I tried to look in the source code of vscode but I couldn't find it. I haven't tried IDEA tho.